# In unity how can I make a checkpoint system

Tags: unity, 2d, platform

I have a `2D platformer` and if my player dies, he goes back to the start, but I want there to be checkpoints.

My current Respawn script:

```csharp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PlayerPrefab;
    public Transform SpawnPoint;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Trap")
        {
            PlayerPrefab.transform.position = SpawnPoint.transform.position;
        }
    }
 

}
```

I don't know how to implement checkpoints into this.

Comment: Do exactly the same with a checkpoint. If you collide with the checkpoint, save the transform.

Comment: So if I hit a checkpoint cooler I save that pos to the spawn point but does that work for multiple checkpoints like checkpoint(01) and checkpoint(02)

Comment: If you save them to a list or array: yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to structure your project a bit differently. Instead of having the `Respawn` script on the player (I assume it's on the player) detect and handle all the interactions with different objects in the world, you should make those objects themselves responsible for detecting the player and triggering a response from it.

So first of all, don't make the player a trigger. Give it a Rigidbody2D, so it can be detected by trigger areas (if you don't want to use the Unity physics and handle movement yourself, make it kinematic). Turn the `private void OnTriggerEnter2D` into a `public void DieAndRespawn()` method which can be called by other scripts if they want the player to die and respawn. Note that when this script is on the player, it doesn't need an explicit reference to the player because it can just access the properties of the gameObject it's on directly.

```
public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform spawnPoint;

    public void DieAndRespawn()
    {
         Debug.Log("Nooooooooo!");
         transform.position = spawnPoint.transform.position;
    }
}
```

Then create separate scripts for `Trap` and `Checkpoint`. Give the objects they are on Colliders with "Is Trigger?" enabled, so they can detect the player and cause something to happen to it. Their collision methods then would look like this for the Trap component:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
     Respawn respawn = other.GetComponent<Respawn>();
     if (respawn != null) {
          Debug.Log(other.name + " ran into " + name);
          respawn.DieAndRespawn();
     }    
}
```

And like this for the Checkpoint component:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
     Respawn respawn = other.GetComponent<Respawn>();
     if (respawn != null) {
          Debug.Log("Setting spawn point of " + other.name + " to location of " + name);
          respawn.spawnPoint = gameObject.transform;
     }    
}
```

Note that these traps and checkpoints don't recognize the player by a tag, but instead by having a specific component. That means that they can now not just interact with the player but also with anything else which has the `Respawn` component. Like for example a second player or an AI actor which you want to die and respawn just like a human player.

Comment: so the checkpoint script gores on my checkpoint spritwe

Comment: @elliot727 Yes. `Checkpoint` goes on the checkpoints, `Trap` goes on the traps and `Respawn` goes on the object you want to respawn (like the player).

Answer (score 0):

You clearly know how to move the player to a spawn point when hitting a trap.

You can use the same logic to move the spawn point to a checkpoint when hitting the checkpoint.

Comment: donset work
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
     {
         if (other.gameObject.tag == "Checkpoint")
         {
             SpawnPoint.transform.position = PlayerPrefab.transform.position;
         }
    }
    }
 

}

Comment: I am a tad confused, actually. Why are you moving a prefab rather than the GO that hit the trap?

Comment: I set the spawn pos to where the player hit the checkpoint but idk